# Create an array of css classes to add/remove them using wildcards

Tags: jquery, html, css

Thanks to the excellent PHPExcel class I made a script that converts an XLS or XSLX file to an HTML table. To the HTML table are applyed CSS styles to create a nice layout. The Excel file may have embedded styles too such as cells background and/or foreground colors and during conversion I'm keeping these styles too. The generated HTML code is stored into a MYSQL dB as a string and then displayed with a simple `echo` when requested.

**My script reads the Excel embedded styles, convert them into CSS classes and save them into the HTML code like this:**

```
<style>
    .excelBackColor_FFFF00 { background-color: #FFFF00 !important; }
    .excelBackColor_3F48CC { background-color: #3F48CC !important; }
    .excelForeColor_FF0000 { color: #FF0000 !important; }
</style>
```

The reason I decided to write the classes this way are:

1. Excel cells may have more than one background color (A1 -> yellow, B4 -> red, C8 -> blue, etc.)
2. the `!important` property is needed to override the CSS file used to style the HTML table
3. I need to use classes because **my goal is to use JQuery to add/remove these classes** with a click

I did find the way to **remove** classes using wildcards, but after a lot of attempts I think it is not possible to **add** the removed classes using wildcards! 
To add or remove classes I need to know their names, but due to the fact that these classes are created during the conversion procedure I can know their names only by parsing the HTML, so I believe that the only way to get the classes' names is to create an array of these classes and then add/remove the classes by applying wildcards.

Would you please help me to:

1. **get the class names and write them into an array**
2. **explain me how to retrieve the classes from the array and add/remove them using wildcards** so that I can remove for example all background colors by simply acting on `.excelBackColor*` and then adding them back the same way with a click.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9h3ymz1w/

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want an array with ALL classes of EVERY td element? Or of one specific? If so, how do you want to identify it and how would this action be triggered. Also: If you want do add them back you need some way to store it.

Comment: @Øle Bjarnstroem. I would like to save only the names of the those classes inside the <style> tag into an array. Then I would like to trigger them by getting their names from the array but applying the wildcards first so that I can add/remove all of them by calling for i.e. ' excelBackColor* '

Comment: @Christoph. No, I need to add/remove all  'excelBackColor_* ' classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick. Just don't exclusively use jQuery but also javascript and regular expressions. To learn more about regex you can visit regex101.com.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <style id="excel-style">
          .excelBackColor_FFFF00 { background-color: #FFFF00 !important; }
          .excelBackColor_3F48CC { background-color: #3F48CC !important; }
          .excelForeColor_FF0000 { color: #FF0000 !important; }
          .someother_class {}
          p {}
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function() {
            // DOM is ready
            // PART 1
            var excel_style = $("#excel-style").html();
            // parse using regex to get an array of all classes that start with '.excel'
            var excel_classes = excel_style.match(/\.excel[a-z0-9\-_]+/gi);

            // PART 2
            // function to remove all classes using 'wildcards'
            function removeExcelBackColor() {
              // first match all elements with a selector
              $("[class^='.excelBackColor']").each(function( index ) {
                // now get all the classes as a string in a temp var
                var tmp_classes = $(this).attr('class');
                // remove every class that starts with .excelBackColor
                var clean_classes = tmp_classes.replace(/\.excelBackColor[a-z0-9\-_]+/gi, '');
                // assign leftover classes
                $(this).attr('class', clean_classes);
              });
            }

            // Call our function.
            removeExcelBackColor();

            // you could bind that to a click event like so:
            $("#mybutton").click(function() {
              removeExcelBackColor();
            });

          });
        </script>


    </head>
    <body>
      <table id="excel_table">
          <tr>
            <td class=".excelBackColor_FFFF00 other_class">data 1</td>
            <td class=".excelBackColor_3F48CC keep_this_class">data 2</td>
            <td class=".excelForeColor_FF0000">data 3</td>
          </tr>
      </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Excellent, it works! I just changed the ^ to * to match the class when it did not happened to be at the beginning. Now "part 3" :-) can I do the same to add the same classes back (toggle)? Many thanks

Comment: Well I showed you how to retrieve them. Storing them in a javascript variable and then adding them back based on certain criteria shouldn't be a problem. Just try and learn.